# Axial Convolution of Plane and Spherical DiracDelta?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, convolution

I'd like to evaluate this convolution to a function of r, z and r0 giving a density for the resulting region:

$\boldsymbol{\pi}(z) \ast \delta(r-r0)$

WHERE

$\boldsymbol{\pi}(z)$ is an xy planar region at z

and

$\delta(r-r_0)$ is a spherical shell of radius r0 .

I've tried a number of approaches, including:

- `Convolve[DiracDelta...`
- `Region`s and/or `ShellRegion`
- `RegionDilation`/`RegionErosion`
- variations on FromSphericalCoordinates
  and others I've probably forgotten.

Failing a solution to my specific challenge, are there any examples of, at least, multidimensional `Convolve` with radial `DiracDelta` between surfaces of different dimensionality (of course, both residing in the same embedding space)?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and the problems you encountered.

Comment: OK but it will take me a while to reconstruct my failed approaches because I didn't save them.